# Eclipse Class File Editor Source not Found when adding library to java project

Tags: java, eclipse, libraries

[image]

I tried to add a library to my java project in the form of a .jar file however when trying to view any files contained within the library this banner is displayed above them. I'm using eclipse IDE do I need to worry about this and if I do how do I go about fixing it?

Comment: That means you don't have the Java source files to go with the Class files in the jar - that is normal for a jar. You may be able to download the source files and use Attach Source.

Comment: I'm trying to use this library: https://github.com/stelar7/R4J/releases/
Would I need to download the zip and attach that or is it something else? Sorry if this is obvious I've never done this before

Comment: You don't need anything else to use that jar. You only need the source if you want to read the Java code to see how it works

Answer (score 0):

If you have the RJ4-2.0.6's source, you can zip it and set the path's zip file clicking in the attach source's button below:

[image]